# Integrating CMake to Qt Project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, cmake, cl

I am trying to integrate simple project in QT with CMake. 
There is so many problem and solution proposals but none of them solved the problem.
I've just crated a simple QT Widget application and prepared CMakeLists.txt. When I open it with Qt creator, I am getting the errors below

> "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: cl is not a full path and was not found in the
>   PATH. To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from
>   a shell that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This
>   environment is unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem,
>   run cmake from the Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat). Tell
>   CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full
>   path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH."
>
> "The C++ compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0/VC/BIN/amd64/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program. It fails with the following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-pcEtcD/qtc-cmake-MWKmhCFk/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>   Run Build Command:"jom" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_7c235\fast" The system cannot
>   find the file specified Generator: execution of make failed. Make
>   command was: "jom" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_7c235\fast"

I got nothing from these errors

Comment: And it makes sense to read through?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that jom.exe is in your path. I had the same problem and solved it by adding the path to jom.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Run the commands from the `Visual Studio Command Prompt`. Should be most top entry of the Start menu (in Windows 7).